# Get user details on combo box change

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, combobox

I need the code for getting the `addr` and `pnum` of the patient when I choose the `pname` in the combo box.

How can I do that?

```
<script>

function getVal() {
    document.getElementById("text2").value = document.getElementById("model").value;
}
</script>   

<body>
//code in opening and getting my addr and pnum in dbase

<?php
include('connect.php');
$pname=$_GET['tpname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient where pname='$pname'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $pnum=$row['pnum'];
            $addr=$row['addr']; 
}
?>

//code for choosing pname

<tr><td>Patient Name:
<div id="ma">
<select name="pname" class="textfields" id="model"  style="width:180px;" onchange="getVal();">
    <option id="0" >--Select Patient Name--</option>
     <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
        $pnum=$_GET['pnum'];
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $pnum = $row['pnum'];
            $pname = $row['pname'];
    ?>
    <option id="<?php echo $pnum; ?>" value="<?php echo $pname; ?>"><?php echo $pname; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

//code for getting pname and addr

Address:<input type="text" name="ename" size="20"  id="ma" value="<?php echo $addr ?>"/>
Name:<input type="text" name="ename" size="20"  id="ma" value="<?php echo $pname ?>"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function getVal()
{
  var pname=$('#model option:selected').val();
  var pnum=$('#textboxidofpnum').val();
  var addr=$("#ma").val();
  console.log(pname,pnum,addr);

}
```

Comment: but my pnum is also a textbox

Comment: then change  var pnum=$('#textboxid').val()

Comment: <?php
 include('connect.php');
 $pname=$_GET['tpname'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient where pname='$pname'");
 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   
    
    $pnum=$row['pnum'];
    $addr=$row['addr'];
   
 }
 ?>

Comment: this is how i open my connection..and get the value in database ..am i correct?

Comment: i put the value of pname in the tpname